# Powers of automorphic Eisenstein series

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $G$ be a reductive group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $P$ be a standard parabolic subgroup of $G$ with Levi decomposition
$$P = MN.$$
We denote by $R_{disc,M}$ the discrete spectrum of $M$. Let $I_{M}^G(I_{N(\mathbb{A})}\otimes R_{disc,M})$ be the induced representation. For $\Phi\in I_{M}^G(I_{N(\mathbb{A})}\otimes R_{disc,M})$ we define an Eisenstein serie as follows
$$E(g,\Phi,s) = \sum_{\gamma\in P(\mathbb{Q})\setminus G(\mathbb{Q})}\Phi(\gamma g)e^{<\rho_P,H_P(\gamma g)>},$$
where $\rho_P$ is the Weyl vector and $H_P$ is the map
\begin{align}
H_P:\;P&\to Hom(Char(P),\mathbb{R}),\\
g&\mapsto (\chi\in Char(P)\mapsto log(|\chi(g)|)),
\end{align}
with $Char(P)$ the group of rational characters of $P$. Let
$$\mathbf{E}(g) = E(g,\Phi,s)^2,$$
is there any way to understand $\mathbf{E}(g)$ as an Eisenstein serie of $G$? I mean, is there any section $\phi\in I_{M}^G(I_{N(\mathbb{A})}\otimes R_{disc,M})$ such that
$$\mathbf{E}(g) = \sum_{\gamma\in P'(\mathbb{Q})\setminus G(\mathbb{Q})}\Phi(\gamma g)e^{<\rho_{P'},H_{P'}(\gamma g)>},$$
for some parabolic $P'$?.

Comment: Typically, no. Because, square of an Eisenstein series will have non-zero components in most representations in the spectral decomposition. Take a cusp form $\phi$ and a maximal parabolic Eisenstein series $E$ on $\mathrm{GL}(n)$. If there were an Eisenstein series $\mathbb{E}=E^2$ then
$$0 = \langle \phi,\mathbb{E}\rangle = \langle \phi\bar{E},E\rangle.$$
However, the last inner product is the global zeta integral of $\phi\otimes E$ and typically does not vanish identically.

Comment: Thank you, under what conditions the product is an Eisenstein series? Is the vanishing of the global zeta integral of $\phi\otimes E$ enough? Is there another similar criterion for integer powers of Eisenstein series?